# Old iOS6 app is now crashing when trying to open in iOS8

Tags: crash, ios8

I'm trying to fix a legacy app (hasn't been updated to iOS7 or above. Still shows iOS6 UI). Whenever the app tries to open, it crashes. I found the problem at the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method when I set the tab bar controller.

```
[self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
```

I get this error:

```
 CRASH: *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

This is the Stack Trace:

```
2014-09-27 01:08:35.517 AppName[2919:1348769] Stack Trace: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x233dde57 <redacted> + 150
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x30a8bc8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x232f2e9d CFRunLoopRemoveTimer + 0
3   AppName                          0x000940eb -[NSArray(UtilityExtensions) firstObject] + 46
4   UIKit                               0x2694a93d <redacted> + 400
5   UIKit                               0x269b869f <redacted> + 254
6   AppName                          0x00137fa3 -[FirstChildViewController viewWillAppear:] + 126
```

So I understand that bug to be something where its assumed I'm trying to access an item in an array where none exists. But the tab controller shows a count of all the view controllers it should have. So Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Again, this ONLY happens when I try to build and run for iOS8.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The stack trace doesn't have anything obvious about a number of view controllers.  `CFRunLoopRemoveTimer` seems to be a hint.  Is there anything in either "FirstChildViewController viewWillAppear:" or "NSArray(UtilityExtensions) firstObject" that is related to timers?

Comment: Yeah, thats the weird part, since FirstChildViewController is init and added to the tabcontroller before the setRootViewController method is called. And I have a breakpoint in viewWillAppear which never gets trigger (I guess for obvious reasons). The NSArray(UtilityExtensions) methods never seems to called in the app.

Comment: OK, but it's not the `init` that's on the stack.  Setting the root view controller is probably triggering `viewWillAppear:`.  I'm still back at wondering about whether anything in the view controller or associated code uses a timer.

Comment: Found the possible problem. Turns out there was an old NSArray category with a firstObject method. Definitely caused the conflict with the default method that already has this. Appreciate the feedback since it got me pointed in the right direction.